# How to use node.js Context.IO behind a department proxy?

Tags: email, node.js, rest, proxy, socks

Here is my node.js code to use Context.IO in a RESTful way rather than IMAP.

```
var ContextIO = require('contextio');
var ctxioClient = new ContextIO.Client({
  key: 'MY_KEY',
  secret: 'MY SECRET'
});
ctxioClient.accounts().get(function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(res);
});
```

When I executed the above code on my dormitory computer, everything worked fine. However, when I executed the code on my office computer, which is behind a departmental proxy, the code simply timed out. My department provides both http and socks proxies for internet access. The question is how to set it up in node.js?

By the way, I also tried

```
socksify node code.js
```

It did not time out. Instead, it just did not response.

Comment: If you want to contact us via support AT context DOT io, we can troubleshoot this with you and see whether the calls even make it to the endpoint and if they do, figure out what is it the proxy is doing that is causing issues.